# How to enter a value in a single cell in a range and continue through each cell in the range

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a range A6:A24 that is blank. I want to paste the value 1 into each cell and copy a resulting calculation in H9 to a new sheet. After that I want to move to the next cell paste "1" but delete the previous "1" and paste the resulting value.

I am either able to paste 1 into every box or just the top.

A6:A24 are years. I am trying to pull the calculation for when each year is equal to 1 (100 percent) meaning all other years need to be equal to zero.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim inputRange1 As Range
Dim inputRange2 As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim b As Range
Dim j As Long

Set dvCell2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:A24")

Set inputRange2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")

Set dvCell1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")

Set inputRange1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:B24")

i = 1
j = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each b In inputRange2
    dvCell2.Value = b.Value
    For Each c In inputRange1
        dvCell1.Value = c.Value
        Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(i + 2, j + 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("H9").Value
        i = i + 1
    Next c
    j = j + 1   
    i = 1
Next b
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow. This will loop through each cell in `dvcell2` and put a 1 in it and then copy the value of H9. I'm not sure if you're attempting to do something else.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim inputRange1 As Range
Dim inputRange2 As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim b As Range
Dim j As Long

Set dvcell2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6:A24")
Set inputRange2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1")
Set dvCell1 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")
Set inputRange1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6:B24")

i = 1
j = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each b In dvcell2
    dvcell2.value=0
    b.Value = 1
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(i + 2, j + 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("H9").Value
    j = j + 1
Next b

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you SJR for answering. Sorry I was not clear, so I want to paste 1 in A6 (All others would be zero) copy H9, then I want to paste 1 in A7 and remove it from A6 so it is zero and paste H9. Then next I want A8 to be 1 and A6 and A7 to be zero  Each time i do this I want to copy H9. But I can't seem to write it and the code given gives me the error"subscript out of range" Thanks again!

Comment: The code above does what you describe I think. Which line errors? Check your sheet names are correct (I haven't changed any of that from your original code).

Comment: You are right I mistyped a sheet name, however the code isn't zeroing out the previous ones, I'm getting the cumulative numbers (like if A6 and A7 both had zeros in it) But seriously thank you for all your help! Do you think I have to write another loop to create the zeros or can they not run simultaneously? Sorry for asking so much!

Comment: I've added a line - can you give it another go? I'm assuming you need every cell to be set explicitly to zero other than the one in question?